# The server hangs when trying to execute "page_title();"

Tags: php

I'm trying to store the current page title inside a PHP variable, but the server hangs when I try to fetch the page title.

**page_title():**

```
function page_title($url) {
    $fp = file_get_contents($url);

    if (!$fp) 
        return null;

    $res = preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/siU", $fp, $title_matches);

    if (!$res) 
        return null; 

    $title = preg_replace('/\bReactionDB\b/i',' ', $title_matches[1]);
    $title = preg_replace('/\|/', '', $title);              
    $title = trim($title);

    return $title;
}
```

**curPageURL():**

```
function curPageURL() {    
    $pageURL = 'http';

    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {
        $pageURL .= "s";
    }

    $pageURL .= "://";

    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }

    return $pageURL;
}
```

The server hangs when trying to execute `page_title();` for 10-20 seconds before giving up.

```
$domene = curPageURL(); 
$pagetitle = page_title($domene);
```

I've tested `page_title();` to see if it works at all. If I put in an external URL, it shows the page title of the page with no problems, but I need it to fetch the page title of the current page/url.

I've also tested the output of `curPageURL();` and it does fetch the complete URL of the current webpage.

If there is a solution for this, it must include the ability to store the fetched page title into a PHP variable (`$pagetitle`).

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to get the page_title() of the current URL? Isn't thereby that function recursively (with extraneous HTTP requests) calling itself?

Comment: @mario That's right. I'm trying to get the page_title of the current URL. Hmmm, do you mean that it's going into an infinite loop? 
(English is my second language, but I'm trying my best to follow)

Comment: @MikeB I won't argue with you on that. Hmm. Is there any other way to retrieve page title+url of the current page, and also be able to store those values in php variables?

Seems like I have some code to rewrite :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `curl` instead of `file_get_contents` and see if the same thing happens:

```
function url_get_contents($url) {
    if (!function_exists('curl_init'))
        return null;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $res = preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/siU", $output, $title_matches);

    if (!$res) 
        return null; 

    $title = preg_replace('/\bReactionDB\b/i',' ', $title_matches[1]);
    $title = preg_replace('/\|/', '', $title);              
    $title = trim($title);

    return $output;
}

$domene = curPageURL(); 
$pagetitle = url_get_contents($domene);
```

**Update**

An example script:

```
<?php
$script     = explode('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$scriptname = $script[count($script) - 1];

switch($scriptname) {
    case 'index.php':
        $title = 'Welcome';
    break;

    case 'about.php':
        $title = 'About Us';
    break;

    default:
        $title = '';
}
?>
<title><?php if ($title != '') { echo $title . ' | '; } ?>ReactionDB</title>
```

Now you can use `$title` wherever else for when you need it.

Comment: The second and third `preg_replace` can also be substituted with `$title = str_replace("Reaction | ", "", $title_matches[1]);`

Comment: Thanks for replying! I tried the code and the same thing happens.
I monitored the server at the same time and the memory usage shot through the roof and halted the server. 
I'm starting to believe that what I'm trying to accomplish must be done in an entirely different way.

Comment: If you're using Chrome / Firefox / another browser that can show you the size of the page and it's over 100 KB, this idea might not be feasible and you'd be better off writing a different function in your header or function that outputs the header, for storing the page title.

Comment: Example script added to my answer. If you have hundreds or even thousands of pages, disregard my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I will check it out later today, something just came up.
I'll let you know how it goes :)